# How to find the Difference between each row from 2 columns, but some fields from either columns are NULL?

Tags: mysql

Say I have 2 columns,

[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dQby.png)

How do I find the difference between the values of each row from these 2 columns?

I noticed the last row has a null, and since (4 - null) isn't possible, any suggestions for this?

I tried IFNULL to change the null to 0, but (4 - null) still returns NULL as a result.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/62576)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider table name is test and columns are A and B. Then query will be

```
SELECT COALESCE(A, 0) - COALESCE(B, 0) AS diff from test
```

Comment: Thanks! It's able to calculate now, null is changed to 0 (integer).